# Google Book API - Thumbnail image in .NET MAUI

Tags: .net, maui

I am playing with the `CollectionView` in a .NET MAUI app with content from the Google Book API.

How do I show the thumbnail as an image?

Here is an example of the thumbnail that is returned from the Book API:

[http://books.google.com/books/publisher/content?id=\_iSECwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&imgtk=AFLRE728aVc5mHHyY3224gt6hPgHPfhR5_QbpmqsPEFxnuScVPg4in1dfjzsCYcGJMzcshcKA1tE9tJMAYbZ-Cavt4bmoPO-hiiD3ldPMfhFSrxtmafccEpZzxxXJ_CiRHofH8Z__XQq&source=gbs_api](http://books.google.com/books/publisher/content?id=%5C_iSECwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&imgtk=AFLRE728aVc5mHHyY3224gt6hPgHPfhR5_QbpmqsPEFxnuScVPg4in1dfjzsCYcGJMzcshcKA1tE9tJMAYbZ-Cavt4bmoPO-hiiD3ldPMfhFSrxtmafccEpZzxxXJ_CiRHofH8Z__XQq&source=gbs_api)

I have tried to bind the `ImageUrl` property, where I store the returned thumbnail, to the `Image` source.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Please show your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can download and display the remote image by specifying a URI as the value of the `Source` property like below:

```
<Image Source="https://aka.ms/campus.jpg" />
```

The equivalent C# code is:

```
Image image = new Image
{
    Source = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri("https://aka.ms/campus.jpg"))
};
```

**Update:**

```
 <Image Source="http://books.google.com/books/publisher/content?id=\_iSECwAAQBAJ&amp;printsec=frontcover &amp; img=1&amp;zoom=1&amp;edge=curl&amp;imgtk=AFLRE728aVc5mHHyY3224gt6hPgHPfhR5_QbpmqsPEFxnuScVPg4in1dfjzsCYcGJMzcshcKA1tE9tJMAYbZ-Cavt4bmoPO-hiiD3ldPMfhFSrxtmafccEpZzxxXJ_CiRHofH8Z__XQq&amp;source=gbs_api 

"></Image>
```

Comment: That's not going to help if Johan wants to bind to a property. We need to see his code to find out what's wrong.

Comment: That is how I tried to do it. If you take the example url and past it in the browser the image appears and when you past it in the image source you get "Entity references or sequences beginning with an ampersand '&' must be terminated with a semicolon ';'" How can I solve this?

Comment: This is because that you need to use `&amp;` to encode the ampersand. I have updated my solution, you can refer to it.

Comment: Hi Johan, I haven't heard from you for a few days. May I confirm if there is anything else that I can help here?